# XSD validation for maxOccurs of element with child with particular content

Tags: xml, xsd

I would want to validate some XML with the pattern

```
<T1>
 <T2>
  <Flag>F1</Flag>
  <someNodes></someNodes>
 </T2>
 <T2>
  <Flag>F2</Flag>
  <someNode></someNode>
 </T2>
 <T2>
  <Flag>F3</Flag>
  <someNode></someNode>
 </T2>
</T1>
```

I would want such that

1. in every T1, there can only be maximum of 6 T2
2. in every T1, there can only be maximum of 1 T2 with element Flag as child with value F3

is that doable? what kind of keywords should I search tutorial for?

Answer (score 0):

this could solve your problem?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Data_XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Data_XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Data_XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Data_XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="T1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="T1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="T2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="6">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="flag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>          
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>      
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```